# Can we collect YouTube posts using API where channel is mentioned

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch youtube posts data through API where YouTube channel is mentioned.
I am not able to find any documentation for it in link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs

Thanks,
Shashikant

Comment: What do you mean by (quote) *youtube posts data*? Be more specific.

Comment: I want to collect Youtube videos where channel is mentioned.
Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLmJEBqXs1A
In above video **India Yamaha Motor** is mentioned

Answer (score 0):

For collect YouTube videos where a certain channel is mentioned (*i.e: **`India Yamaha Motor`** like in your example*), you can use the `search.list` endpoint of the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) for retrieve videos that matches with the query.

Example:

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=50&q=%40India%20Yamaha%20Motor&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN] Accept: application/json
```

Where **`q`** is the text to search, in this case, **`@India Yamaha Motor`**

[This is the search.list sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22q%22%3A%22%40India%20Yamaha%20Motor%22%7D) you can query it online and see the results.